# Mocking a property on a py file, to return value instead of method

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I have this code in derived.py I want to test.

```
tigerContracts  = ['Element1','Element2']
def getReportingID(tigerKey):
    dig = '2' if tigerKey in tigerContracts else '0'
    return dig
```

My unit test is this:

```
class GeneratorDerived(unittest.TestCase):

    def tigerContracts(self):
        return ['Element3']

    @patch('derived.tigerContracts')
    def test_getReportingID(self, mockFunc):

        mockFunc.return_value = self.tigerContracts()

        reportingID = derived.getReportingID('XX-XX')
        self.assertEqual(reportingID,'0')

        reportingID = derived.getReportingID('Element3')
        self.assertEqual(reportingID,'2')
```

My problem is, I am getting the method as a return value.

MagicMock name='tigerContracts' id='138171616'

Instead, I would want the return value to be

['Element3']

Comment: In other words, while performing the test, value for tigerContracts in method  getReportingID is as <BR>"MagicMock name='tigerContracts' id='138171616'" <BR>instead of <BR>['Element3']

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/python-mocking-you-are-a-tricksy-beast-6c4a1f8d19b2) Does a great job of explaining exactly this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is more what you are looking for, to get an explanation:
when we call self.tigerContracts() a new mock is created and returned. Per my comment: [Full explanation](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/python-mocking-you-are-a-tricksy-beast-6c4a1f8d19b2)

```html
import unittest
import derived
from mock import patch
class GeneratorDerived(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_getReportingID(self):
        with patch('derived.tigerContracts', 'Element3'):

                reportingID = derived.getReportingID('XX-XX')
                self.assertEqual(reportingID,'0')

                reportingID = derived.getReportingID('Element3')
                self.assertEqual(reportingID,'2')
```

Comment: Yeah, this one worked. But I am really keen on your suggested post. Thanks a ton